# Tenacious integrals for a radio-astronomical survey

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

I have a pair of integrals to evaluate (to do with the probability of detecting a galaxy in a radio astronomy survey, given a known sensitivity function, but the context is not especially important). Ideally I want to do this symbolically, because it's all going into a Monte-Carlo sampling setup, implying many evaluations for various values of the parameters $a$ and $b$. The limits of integration are some finite constant (lower bound) and infinity (upper bound), although with that exponential cutoff a sufficiently large finite upper bound would give a good approximation.

$$\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{Ax^2+Bx+C}}10^{ax}\exp(-10^{bx})\,{\rm d}x$$

$$\int\frac{x}{\sqrt{Ax^2+Bx+C}}10^{ax}\exp(-10^{bx})\,{\rm d}x$$

As I strongly suspect there is no analytic solution, I'm also interested in e.g. series approximations, especially any that converge reasonably quickly...

Comment: Are $A$, $B$, $c$ fixed for all computations?

Comment: What are the conditions for the given constants?

Comment: @Sal A, B and C are known, fixed constants. a and b are parameters to be optimized.

Comment: @LaxmiNarayanBhandari the integration bounds are either x=0 to some positive, finite x, or some positive, finite x to inf. A, B and C are guaranteed to keep that denominator real over the domain of integration. a can in principle have any value, but I could impose a>0 if that's useful as that's expected (though not guaranteed) on physical grounds. b>0.

Comment: @Kyle well, in that many uncertainties, one has to calculate the integral for evey single case, which is just tiresome.